# Knock to unlock on Android device

Tags: android, android-studio, accelerometer, android-sensors, mobile-development

I found that it is possible to make "knock to unlock" http://www.knocktounlock.com/ using accelerometer.

I found this for swift: [Swift CoreMotion detect Tap or Knock on device while in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619778/swift-coremotion-detect-tap-or-knock-on-device-while-in-background)

Is there anyone who is interested in making it for android? I am really new on mobile development.

I would appreciate it so much if you share some source code in android java!

Best regards,

Mudin

Comment: What are you asking here? You have links to a couple tutorials on how to do knock-to-unlock but that is about it. If you are curious how to make one of those, you have already provided yourself a tutorial on how to do this. I would mosey through that tutorial. This is not the place to ask for things of this nature.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am asking what I don't know and looking for someone WHO has ever done this before for android!